# VS code compiles every <fllename>.java file inside the folder which I don't want

Tags: java, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

[image]I am a beginner in java.
I have made folder named 'JavaWork'.  Inside it when I make two or more files of java (e.g. filename1.java and filename2.java), it compiles both of these files and shows the errors and problems of one file in another. I didn't even compile the first file, but it shows its errors on the second one.
To fix it, I tried to make folders inside the parent folder('JavaWork'), and have the filename.java files(or code) inside them, but it still compiles all of them and shows their errors in one another even if I compile only one of them. Please provide a good explanation for this behaviour, does it only  happen in VS code? Or is it the behaviour of Java. How can I fix this and why is this happening?

I am attaching a image so you can understand my problem : FirstJava.java, Student.java, waste.java are three different files but I am getting errors from all of them at the same time, instead from the one which I run or debug.

Comment: VSCode is a good editor, but I don't think it is the best choice for a learner. I would suggest you to use an IDE a bit more mature in Java world like Eclipse for example: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ Simply download it and enjoy it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but could you provide an answer for why this is happening, why it is showing error of another file in the file on which I am currently working right on.